# Appending string to a line read from file places appended string on next line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .`txt` file like the following:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Now, I want to add some string behind each row directly. However, my output is:

```
abc
---testdef
---testghi---test
```

My code is as follows:

```
file_read = open("test.txt", "r")
lines = file_read.readlines()
file_read.close()
new_file = open("res.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    new_file.write(line + "---test")  # I tried to add "\r" in the middle of them, but this didn't work.
new_file.close()
```

Comment: When the file is read, the newline is included in the strings...

Comment: @JiříBaum so how to solve this problem:)

Comment: Sidenote: best practice for opening files is using `with` like `with open(filename) as f: data = f.read()`. It's covered in the official tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Can you please provide us your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to strip the new line using `.rstrip()`:

```py
for line in lines:
    new_file.write(f"{line.rstrip()}---test\n")
```

Then, `res.txt` contains:

```
abc---test
def---test
ghi---test
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, you want to add a string behind a string, for example "abcd" should be changed into "---testabcd".

So the mistake you made is in `new_file.write(line + "---test")`, if you want add string1 before a string2, then you have to specify string1 first then string2.

So change it to`new_file.write("---test" + line)`

Tip: Instead of using '+' operator, use `f strings` or `.format`.

> `f"---test{line}"` this is f string.

> "Hello {friends}".format(friends="myname")

---

For use of '\r':

Whenever you will use this special escape character \r, the rest of the content after the \r will come at the front of your line and will keep replacing your characters one by one until it takes all the contents left after the \r in that string.

`print('Python is fun')`

> Output: Python is fun

Now see what happens if I use a carriage return here

`print('Python is fun\r123456')`

> Output: 123456 is fun

So basically, it just replaces indexes of string to character after \r.